# Adding error message just below the fields in Visualforce page

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I have two fields in a form.I have applied various custom validation using javascript on first field.So I want to display Error meassage just below the field if value entered by user fails the validations.But problem here is user can add as many row as he want using an 'Add Row' button available.So Suppose user adds 3 rows.And the error is in second row , "error value" message should be displayed just below the field of second row.Following is part of my code inside form.So How do I display error using javascript solely(Not using controller class).Please help.

```
                                                  <apex:outputPanel id="List">
                                                        <div id="repayid">
                                                            <table style="width:100%;display: block;overflow: scroll;" id="Table">
                                                                <tr id="Tabletr1">

                                                                    <td class="A">Alpha No</td>

                                                                    <td class="A">BetaText</td>


                                                                </tr>

                                                                <apex:repeat value="{!List}" var="rep" id="addrow">
                                                                    <tr id="repayTabletr2">


                                                                        <td id ="tdid">
                                                                            <apex:inputField value="{!rep.S_Code_No__c}" id="barid" style="width:100%;"/>
                                                                            <div style="color:red; background-color:white;">
                                                                            <p  class="SError" style="display:none;">Error Value </p>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </td>

                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <apex:inputField styleClass="RequiredField" value="{!rep.C_Code__c}" style="width:100%;"/>
                                                                            <div style="color:red; background-color:white;"></div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                </apex:repeat>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
```

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You must be iterating through the input fields in your javascript function. While iterating each field you will have the ID of the field.

Using javascript and CSS you can insert a new DIV below the input with error and can then style and show error message in that DIV.

Or, you can add a empty DIV inside the repeat tag and can then style/add innerHTML to it if you find a error.